# Transform docker-compose environment variable's value to service ip address

Tags: reactjs, docker

I want to convert the environtment variable's value (it is a service in the same docker-compose.yml file) to the ip of that respective container and i can't achieve this.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./server
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    volumes: 
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
  client:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./client
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes: 
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_HOST=server #I WANT TO TRANSFORM THIS TO THE SERVICE IP
      - REACT_APP_API_PORT=3001
```

When i console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST) i get "server" in the console and i want this to be the ip address of the server (it's an api)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rely on the service or container names instead. They will be resolved by the docker daemon.

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    container_name: myserver
    ...

  client:
    container_name: myclient
    ...
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_HOST=myserver
      - REACT_APP_API_PORT=3001
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer put me in the right path, this works but not what i wanted to do (because it's impossible as far as i know) i wanted to make a fetch from react to the REACT_APP_API_HOST variable but in the console it was logging REACT_APP_API_HOST="server/api/v1/users" (path to the api) instead of the machine's ip (which docker doesn't have access) so... i guess i'll have to use .env variables in the react client with the ip of the server in that file, thank you for your help in this.